Adjusting positioning of items in a CSS grid based on contents
I have a CSS grid with three elements in it. A header and two content areas. My grid is defined as having two 50% width columns
.my-grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

What I am trying to achieve is some repositioning when my header element's content is long enough. Eg:

I do not want to use JS or have to use unique classes to achieve this. I want it to work automatically based on how wide the header is. Is it possible in pure CSS?

No. What you seem to require is float.
